# Processing Images with OCR

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to get all the numerical data from the Mean column with multiple identical pictures as attached. [nonsip2_write_8000M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imYLS.jpg)
The way I do it is by using a cursor position script to get the column of information that I want. However, the first data I get is always a bunch of character while the rest are correctly processed. [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFnlF.png) Even though I rearrange the order of images, the results are the same and I get a bunch of characters for the first data. Is there a better way to do this? I think that I might not have preprocessed the images properly.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import ImageGrab
import sys
import subprocess

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Teseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

Tstamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
report_fname='C:\Test_Automation\excel_file\ocr_'+TStamp+'.csv'
fid_1=open((report_fname),"a")
filename_set = ['nonsip_read_10M.jpg', 'nonsip_read_200M.jpg', 'nonsip_read_8000M.jpg', 'nonsip_read_8000M_long.jpg', 'nonsip_write_10M.jpg', 'nonsip_write_200M.jpg', 'nonsip_write_8000M.jpg', 'nonsip_write_8000M_long.jpg','nonsip2_read_8000M.jpg','nonsip2_write_8000M.jpg']

while filename_set:
filename=filename_set.pop(-1)
print(filename)

img=cv2.imread(filename,0)
cv2.namedWindow("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow("window",img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
x_start=839
x_end=927
y_start=844
y_end=1057
x_interval=(x_end - x_start)/8
y_interval=(y_end - y_start)/8
x1=x_start
y1=y_start
x2=x_end
y2=y_end
for i in range(1,9,1):

y2=int(y_start + i*y_interval)
print(i,x1,y1,x1,y2)
img1=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1,y1,x1,y2))
print("debug1")
img1.save('sc.png')
img1=cv2.imread('sc.png',0)
img1=np.invert(img1)
data=pytesseract.image_to_string(img1, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)
fid_1.write('%s.%s\n'%(filename,data))
y1=y2
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

- 1. Crop the image
- 2. Apply tresholding to the image
- 3. Set page-segmentation-mode to the column read (4)

1. First of all you want the bottom part of the image. Therefore we can crop the image with the ratio:

- a. Get image height (`h`) and width (`w`) values

  - ```py
    h, w = img.shape[:2]  # get height and width
    ```
- b. Set starting `x, y` coordinates.

  - ```
    x = int(w/3)
    y = int((3*h)/4)
    ```
- c. Crop the image

  - ```py
    img = img[y:int(y+h/4), x:x+int(w/5)]
    ```
- Result:

  - [image]

2. Apply thresholding to the cropped area:

   - ```py
     thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
     ```
   - Result:

     - [image]
3. Set `page-segmentation-mode` to the column read, since you want the `mean`column values

   - ```py
     txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 4")
     ```
   - Do a cleaning in the `txt` variable (we want only mean values)

     - ```py
       txt = txt.strip().split("\n")
       for t in txt:
           t = t.split(" ")
           is_cnt_dgt = [i for i in t if i.replace(".", "").isdigit()]
           if len(is_cnt_dgt) != 0:
               print(t[len(t)-2])
       ```
     - Result:

       - ```py
         887.958
         919.142
         846.984
         72.1587
         897.016
         934.200
         857.695
         76.5089
         ```
   - If you don't want to clean your code the result will be:

     - ```py
       ‘Current Mean
       §88529 mV 887.958 mV
       Q2L7B5 mV 919.142 mV
       846308 mV 846.984 mV
       TSATI mV 72.1587 mV
       897.397 mV 897.016 mV
       934378mV 934.200 mV
       856477 mV 857.695 mV
       TI901 mY 76.5089 mV

       es
       ```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("imYLS.jpg")
h, w = img.shape[:2]  # get height and width
x = int(w/3)
y = int((3*h)/4)
img = img[y:int(y+h/4), x:x+int(w/5)]
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 4")
txt = txt.strip().split("\n")
for t in txt:
    t = t.split(" ")
    is_cnt_dgt = [i for i in t if i.replace(".", "").isdigit()]
    if len(is_cnt_dgt) != 0:
        print(t[len(t)-2])
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, "Error, unknown command line argument '--psm4'")

Comment: But there should be a space between psm and 4. It should be psm 4. For instance: `config="--psm 4"`

Comment: oh you are right! Thank you for your help. That was pretty careless of me

Comment: Would it be possible to process multiple images(exactly the same image but different values) from using your code?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: I have tried to used the code on a different picture and the results I got were not consistent. There were some missing values and characters in the result. This was the result that I got. https://imgur.com/a/XmUctcf

Comment: Hmm I see, so did you try with different params?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you try: `thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]`

Comment: And if my above suggestion is not helping you then try, `txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)`

Comment: Yup  I have tried both of your suggestions but it still doesnt work. The results are the same. I will try again with other params.

Comment: I hope you will be successful. If you are not, feel free to unaccept this answer or if you want I can delete the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I shall leave it as it is.

Comment: I have an idea, could you please set your `pytesseract` version to 4.1.1 and try again?